# TestNG BeforeClass and AfterClass methods are using different threads, messing up my implementation of ThreadLocal for parallel execution

Tags: java, multithreading, testng, inheritable-thread-local

I'm using ThreadLocal to manage WebDriver object for parallel execution. I'm executing classes in parallel using TestNG. In each class I have dependent test cases. In @BeforeClass method I'm assigning value to ThreadLocal and in @AfterClass I'm removing it. It works fine if test case does not fail. But when one of the test case fails, @AfterClass is running on different thread and due to which WebDriver object is not removed from ThreadLocal and same thread is being assigned to another class and it reuses WebDriver which was originally created for another class. Is there a way I can force java or testng to use same thread for BeforeClass and AfterClass method?

Code:

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    Driver.getInstance().createNewWebDriver();
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass() {
    Driver.getInstance().closeDriver();
}
```

Driver class code:

```
private static Driver driver;
private final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadLocalWebDriver;

private Driver() {
    threadLocalWebDriver = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
}

public static Driver getInstance() {
    if (driver == null) {
        synchronized (Driver.class) {
            if (driver == null) {
                driver = new Driver();
            }
        }
    }
    return driver;
}

public void createNewWebDriver() {
    if (threadLocalWebDriver.get() == null) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        threadLocalWebDriver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
    }
}

public void closeDriver() {
    if (threadLocalWebDriver.get() != null) {
        threadLocalWebDriver.get().quit();
        threadLocalWebDriver.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of tearing down with `@AfterClass` ? I mean why not `@AfterMethod` ?

Comment: I have test cases dependent on each other using `dependsOnMethod`, if I tear down in `@AfterMethod`, I'll have to reopen chrome for no reason.